# How to add a class to an element when another element gets a class in angular?

Tags: css, angularjs, class, conditional-statements, ng-class

I have a scrollspy directive that adds an ".active" class to a nav item.  When the first nav item has the ".active" class I want my header bar to contain a certain class too.  Attached is a simplified example, but how can I add ".active" to item 1 **by only looking at the classes in item 2**.  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silvajeff/8ne09kex/)

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
        <div id="item1" ng-class="if item2 has class=active then add active class here">Item 1</div>
        <div id="item2" ng-class="myVar">Item 2</div>
</div>

    //I can't use a scope object I can only look at item 2's classes
    <button type="button" ng-click="myVar='active'">Add Class</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="myVar=''">Remove Class</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Click here for live demo.**](https://jsfiddle.net/et1e5ve8/)

You'll need a directive to interact with the element. I would have the directive watch the element's classes and have it call a function from your controller when the classes change. Then, your controller function can apply the logic specific to your need, which is to set a flag letting another element know how to respond.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = function(classes) {
    if (~classes.indexOf('active')) {
      $scope.otherItemIsActive = true;
    }
  };
})
.directive('onClassChange', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      onClassChange: '='
    },
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      $scope.$watch(function() {
         return $element[0].className; 
      }, function(className) {
        $scope.onClassChange(className.split(' '));
      });
    }
  };
})
;
```